# How can I make a POST Request in Swift with parameters using URLSession

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsurlsession, urlsession

I have a post request that I want to make using URLSession.

The post request looks like this:

```
curl -X POST   'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/privatekey/devices/devicekey:executeCommand'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Authorization: authtoken'   --data-raw '{
"command" : "sdm.devices.commands",
"params" : {
  "commandName" : "cmdValue"
 }
}'
```

As this is a POST request, I want to only decode if the response is an error message.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/\(project_id)/devices") else {return}
    
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let cmdParams: [String: String] =  ["command":"sdm.devices.commands", "params" : ["commandName": "cmdValue"]]

do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: cmdParams)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    guard let data = data else {print("empty data"); return }
```

The cmdParams are throwing an error, so I'm not sure how to structure the params request properly, a successful POST will result in the API returning `{}` an unsuccessful request will return some error.

How can I adjust my code to get this working?

Comment: `cmdParams` is `[String:Any]`, not `[String:String]`

Comment: @vadian thanks made that change but still can't get the request to POST.

Comment: `[String:Any]` isn't codable. You either need to create a `struct` to encode the data or directly use a JSON string (as in my answer).

Comment: @BjornB. `JSONSerialization` can serialize `[String:Any]`. It's not about `Codable`

Comment: @vadian You are right.

Comment: @KARL Isn't it `authtoken` rather than `token`?

Comment: The URL is not the same, is that normal?

Comment: maybe google uses `gRPC Transcoding syntax` in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode the JSON string as data. Then you can add it as the `httpBody.` Don't forget to add the token to the request.

```swift
// Encode your JSON data
let jsonString = "{ \"command\" : \"sdm.devices.commands\", \"params\" : { \"commandName\" : \"cmdValue\" } }"
guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return } 

// Send request
guard let url = URL(string: "https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/\(project_id)/devices") else {return}
    
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = jsonData

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // Most likely you want to add some token here
// request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // Handle HTTP request error
    } else if let data = data {
        // Handle HTTP request response
    } else {
        // Handle unexpected error
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks, there's no error messages now but the POST data is still not going through, is there any way I can modify this code to print what the API call is responding with?

Comment: You can, you can print the `data` and the `response`. Take a look the `dataTask` documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask

Comment: Ok i got a `response code 500` which indicates something is wrong with the server I am requesting from right?

Comment: 500 usually is an internal server error. Do you have a status message or response body?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using "urlencoded" to encode your request body. Here is my test code:
(note, since I do not have a paid subscription to this service I cannot fully test my code)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let project_id = 123  // <-- adjust to your needs
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                if let url = URL(string: "https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/\(project_id)/devices") {
                    doPOST(url: url)
                }
            }
    }
    
    func doPOST(url: URL) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // try urlencoding
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // <-- your api "token" here
        
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "command", value: "sdm.devices.commands"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "params", value: "{ \"commandName\" : \"cmdValue\" }")
        ]
        if let query = components.url!.query {
            print("--> query: \(query)")
            request.httpBody = Data(query.utf8)
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            showResponse(data)  // <-- for debuging
            guard error == nil else { print("--> error: \(error)"); return }
            guard let data = data else { print("empty data"); return }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func showResponse(_ data: Data?) {
        if let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers), let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            print("\n---> response: " + String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self))
        } else {
            print("=========> error")
        }
    }
    
}
```

If this does not work, have a look at this doc:

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/executeCommand

In particular: `The URL uses gRPC Transcoding syntax`. It may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
func postRequest(email: String, password: String, onsuccess: @escaping ((Loginproduct?) -> Void)) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://app.omana-app.com/api/login")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("sk_d3KmPtjEtdGTjChLB0ylraAb/AWgfyR9MOxFXwgEWSZsnpoIXFVDfm1Snoak0ufRe0w=", forHTTPHeaderField: "secret_key")
    request.addValue("pk_Bvk6rVC7WxbRW2O3sy4xwCEiM+n8jdT55BQv4BA0zG4IawzpbDhTVzSvj43DcvU7cM0x", forHTTPHeaderField: "publish_key")

    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "device_type": 2,
        "device_token": "abc",
        "role": "4"
    ]

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = response.statusCode
                print("status code = \(statusCode)")

                if statusCode == 200 {
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let loginResponse = try decoder.decode(Loginproduct.self, from: data)

                            // Pass the decoded model to the completion handler
                            onsuccess(loginResponse)
                        } catch {
                            print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                            // Pass nil in case of decoding error
                            onsuccess(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                // Pass nil in case of network error
                onsuccess(nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print("Error creating JSON body: \(error)")
        onsuccess(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

func hit(email:String,password:String){ let Url = String(format: "https://app.omana-app.com/api/login") guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return } let parameters: [String: Any] = [ "email": email, "password": password, "device_type": 2, "device_token": "abc", "role": "4"] var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl) request.httpMethod = "POST" request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") request.setValue("sk_d3KmPtjEtdGTjChLB0ylraAb/AWgfyR9MOxFXwgEWSZsnpoIXFVDfm1Snoak0ufRe0w=", forHTTPHeaderField: "secret_key") request.setValue("pk_Bvk6rVC7WxbRW2O3sy4xwCEiM+n8jdT55BQv4BA0zG4IawzpbDhTVzSvj43DcvU7cM0x", forHTTPHeaderField: "publish_key") guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return } request.httpBody = httpBody request.timeoutInterval = 20 let session = URLSession.shared session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in if let response = response { print(response) } if let data = data { do { let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) print(json) } catch { print(error) } } }.resume() } Heading

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add some explanation how your code will help to solve the question.